# How can I combine both of these conditions? in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-controller

I'am new with laravel. How can I combine both of these conditions?

```
public function student($classroom_id)
    {
        $members = Classroom::findOrFail($classroom_id,)->members->load('role');
        $members = User::where([
            ['role_id', 2]
        ])->get();

        return response()->json($members);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your relationship in the model as well as DB structure? and what are you trying to access with combine?

Comment: Did you want to get a Classroom who have User that have `role_id` 2?

Comment: Yes I want that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function student($classroom_id)
{
    $members = Classroom::whereHas('members.role', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '2');
    })->findOrFail($classroom_id)->members->load('role');

    return response()->json($members);

}
```